# Change output from database to readable output

Tags: php, mysql

I have some code that will fetch some tables from a database.

The data is stored like this:

- There are three options `["1","0","0"]`, `["0","1","0"]`, `["0","0","1"]` – i.e. `[Yes]`, `[No]`, `[Maybe]`.
- And then it could also have text stored, e.g. `["Readable text"]`.

I want to be able to change the output from `["0","0","1"]` to `Maybe` and `["Readable text"]` to `Readable text`. I’m not sure how to go about this.

Here is the code I’m using:

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$result = $wpdb->get_results( "
SELECT stats.*
  FROM wp_wp_pro_quiz_statistic stats
       JOIN wp_wp_pro_quiz_statistic_ref refs on stats.statistic_ref_id = refs.statistic_ref_id
WHERE refs.user_id= $current_user->ID  && refs.quiz_id= 5");
foreach($result as $row) {
echo "<tr><td><b>$row->answer_data</b></td></tr>";
```

I hope someone can help me out.

here is something they used im not sure how to utilize that for what i want though.

```
public function statisticSave($statisticRefModel, $statisticModel) {
                $values = array();

                $refId = null;
                $isOld = false;

                if($refId === null) {

                        $refData = array(
                                        'quiz_id' => $statisticRefModel->getQuizId(),
                                        'user_id' => $statisticRefModel->getUserId(),
                                        'create_time' => $statisticRefModel->getCreateTime(),
                                        'is_old' => (int)$isOld
                        );

                        $refFormat = array('%d', '%d', '%d', '%d');

                        if($statisticRefModel->getFormData() !== null && is_array($statisticRefModel->getFormData())) {
                                $refData['form_data'] = @json_encode($statisticRefModel->getFormData());
                                $refFormat[] = '%s';
                        }

                        $this->_wpdb->insert($this->_tableStatisticRef, $refData, $refFormat);

                        $refId = $this->_wpdb->insert_id;
                }

                foreach($statisticModel as $d) {
                        $answerData = $d->getAnswerData() === null ? 'NULL' : $this->_wpdb->prepare('%s', json_encode($d->getAnswerData()));

                        $values[] = '( '.implode(', ', array(
                                        'statistic_ref_id' => $refId,
                                        'question_id' => $d->getQuestionId(),
                                        'correct_count' => $d->getCorrectCount(),
                                        'incorrect_count' => $d->getIncorrectCount(),
                                        'hint_count' => $d->getHintCount(),
                                        'points' => $d->getPoints(),
                                        'question_time' => $d->getQuestionTime(),
                                        'answer_data' => $answerData
                        )).' )';
                }

                $this->_wpdb->query(
                                'INSERT INTO
                                '.$this->_tableStatistic.' (
                                        statistic_ref_id, question_id, correct_count, incorrect_count, hint_count, points, question_time, answer_data
                                )
                        VALUES
                                '.implode(', ', $values)
                );
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you able to change how the data is being stored?

If so you should implement JSON instead.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php | https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Example:

```
$a = array(0,0,1); // Maybe
//$a = array("Readable Text"); // Readable Text

$a = json_encode($a); // ["0","0","1"]

// Display json as text
$b = json_decode($a, true); // array

if($b[0] == 1){ echo 'Yes'; }
if($b[1] == 1){ echo 'No'; }
if($b[2] == 1){ echo 'Maybe'; }
if(count($b) == 1){ echo 'Readable Text'; } // count items in array
```

Comment: the data is stored somewhat like that.   here is something they used im not sure how to utilize that for what i want though. http://pastebin.com/GEk3bCjq

Comment: I'm away from a computer but will try some thing when I get back to it.

Comment: Thank you for the help with some small mods it seems this will work perfectly.